# How can I make HTTP calls from Perl?

Tags: perl, http

I want to write a Perl script which calls a URL with certain parameters.

Comment: Whenever you want to do something in Perl, start at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org). It has most everything that you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent), or you can use [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::Simple) if you don't need an object.  If you are going to be using the results of the web page to crawl to other pages, such as to extract URLs or get URLs of images, you'll want to use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize), which is a wrapper around [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent) that handles all the HTML parsing for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link action, Alan.  I'd have linked to them myself, but I had a hot game of Super Mario Galaxy 2 with my daughter I had to get back to.

Answer (score 8):

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $result = get($url);
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) module on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

Comment: Or LWP::Simple if you just need something quick and easy.